# Use Potentiometer to change frequency in FM Radio Transmitter

Tags: potentiometer, transmitter, frequency-modulation

I know that in most circuits you use a tank circuit consisting of an inductor and variable capacitor in parallel to generate different frequencies like [this one](http://cdn.instructables.com/FKB/TL4Q/HXHREEN5/FKBTL4QHXHREEN5.LARGE.jpg). However since most cheap trimmer caps are not very user friendly(have to use screwdriver to adjust instead of traditional knob) I wondered if there was a circuit that somehow used a variable resistor to change the frequency. This circuit would be less than 12 volts. This circuit doesn't use of variable cap could I mod it in some way? [image]Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Varactor diodes appear to be your obvious choice for this type of circuit. A reverse biased diode has obviously a high impedance and that suits any tank circuit but, its capacitance can vary with reverse voltage bias changes and this gives you a variable capacitor that is voltage controlled. A lot of RF VCO's use varactor to control frequency of oscillation. Used em love em.

Here's a few ideas for a colpitts oscillator with varactor tuning: -

[image]
[image]

Here's a tuning stage for a receiver: -

[image]

Taken from [here](http://www.abcelectronique.com/annuaire/montages/cache/1560/recepteur-trf-moyenne-frequence.html)

Comment: Could you give me a link to one I don't understand.  Where would I put it in the circuit also? Thank you for your time. Will check when answer.