# Can anyone help me in designing this variable frequency colpitt oscillator?

Tags: oscillator, varactor, varicap

I am basically trying to achieve a variable frequency colpitt oscillator by using a varactor diode to achieve frequency change. However, I am having trouble figuring out how to connect it so that it does not affect the output voltage. As you can see, the diode's anode and the output have the same node. So the output of the oscillator affects the varactor diode which is not what I want. Is there anyway to provide biasing to the varactor diode independently so that I can connect it as a capacitor at the output but the biasing doesn't affect the main circuit. I hope I worded my question properly. Do let me know if it's not clear what I am trying to ask.

Basically what I mean is, how do I control the varactor diode independently in the following circuit.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, I am having trouble figuring out how to connect it so that it does not affect the output voltage.

They ways I've seen it done is by AC coupling the varactor like in this schematic:

[image]

(Source: [Use Potentiometer to change frequency in FM Radio Transmitter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/164008/use-potentiometer-to-change-frequency-in-fm-radio-transmitter))

The 470pF cap is large compared to the BB609's capacitance, so the capacitance of the series combination is determined by the BB609.

You'll find a few other Colpitts-varactor-tuned VCO ideas at the image source link.

Comment: Thank you so much. Atleast the oscillations are stabilised, I have yet to check if the frequency is varying. However, could you please help me understand why this is working. The value of the DC voltage provided doesnot seem to offset the output signal which is kind of strange to me.

Answer (score 0):

Assume that **V1** is the DC supply voltage for the oscillator, and remains constant. The cathode of varactor D1 will always see this average DC voltage of +3.3V. It would be better to connect diode D1 so that its anode is ground-referenced with cathode independent of DC supply; now frequency does not depend on a stable DC supply voltage of V1.
The cathode of varactor D1 can have its DC voltage varied to change oscillator frequency. Capacitor **Ccouple** in series with diode D1 can be adjusted in value so that frequency range of the control voltage is established:

- a small value of **Ccouple** (less than about 56pf) results in a smaller frequency range
- the large value **Ccouple** shown (1nf) results in a larger frequency range.

[image: Varactor control voltage added]

 The resistor added has no current flowing through it, so that all of **Freq control Vin** (a DC variable-voltage) appears at diode D1's cathode.
This is about the simplest modification to your oscillator that achieves your independent-of-bias requirement.

In the modification shown as control voltage increases above ground, frequency increases too. Control voltage can be raised as much as the Varactor D1 allows. Control voltages approaching 0V (or going negative) may kill oscillations, because the varactor becomes forward-biased on oscillation peaks.

Comment: @glen_gleek Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution, however it doesn't seem to help. It made the oscillations unstable, that is they are continuously increasing.

Comment: Keep in mind that adding the frequency-control diode will decrease stability: lowering resonating element Q, and also due to its temperature coefficient.